# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable when using all()

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is simply to check if list is monotonically increasing or decreasing. I am getting following error,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-63c9df4c7243> in <module>
     10 l1 = [75, 65, 35]
     11 l2 = [75, 65, 35, 90]
---> 12 is_monotonoc(l)

<ipython-input-64-63c9df4c7243> in is_monotonoc(list1)
      1 def is_monotonoc(list1):
      2     for i in range(len(list1)-1):
----> 3         print(all(list1[i] <= list1[i+1]) or all(list1[i] >= list1[i+1]))
      4 
      5 def isMonotonic(A):

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: You're calling `all(True)` or `all(False)` because that's what `list1[i] <= list1[i+1]` evaluates to. `all()` expects an iterable such as a list or tuple, not a bool.

Comment: I think you want to get rid of the for-loop and write it into a generator expression inside the `all` call.

Answer (score 1):

You must have some kind of iterable sequence of items inside the `all` call. I think you want to get rid of the for-loop and write it into generator expressions inside the `all` calls.

So where you have:

```
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    print(all(list1[i] <= list1[i+1]) or all(list1[i] >= list1[i+1]))
```

you mean

```
print(all(list1[i] <= list1[i+1] for i in range(len(list1)-1))
          or all(list1[i] >= list1[i+1] for i in range(len(list1)-1)))
```

Comment: Slightly alternative approach: `monotonic = all(x <= y for x, y in zip(list1, itertools.islice(list1, 1, None)))` (and of course the same for `x >= y`)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick I think.

```
l1 = [75, 65, 35]
l2 = [75, 65, 35, 90]

def is_monotonoc(list1):
    up=True
    down=True
    for i in range(len(list1)-1):
        if not list1[i] <= list1[i+1]:
            up=False
        if not list1[i] >= list1[i+1]:
            down=False
    print(down or up)

is_monotonoc(l1)
is_monotonoc(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just capture @Matthis and @khelwood earlier ideas to summarize here:  (credit to them, of course): [Note, if the `strict` in/de-creasing monotonic array is required, then just change `x <= y` to `x < y` (or `x > y`)

```py
def monotonic(lst):
    ''' check if the list is increasing or decreasing'''
    if all(x <= y for x, y in zip(lst, itertools.islice(lst, 1, None))):
        print('List is increasing monotonic list.')
    elif all(x >= y for x, y in zip(lst, itertools.islice(lst, 1, None))):
        print('List is decreasing monotonic list.')
    else:
        print('List is neither increasing nor decreasting monotonic list.')
```

Outputs:

```
>>> lst
[75, 65, 55, 40]
>>> monotonic(lst)
List is decreasing monotonic list.
'''
```